# Transpose matrix property

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Is well known that this equality is true:

$(A^{-1})^T=(A^{T})^{-1}$

But does that mean that if a square matrix $A$ has an inverse, than the square matrix $A^T$ also has an inverse?

Comment: Yes, it does mean that.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

If $AA^{-1}=I$ than
$$
\left( AA^{-1}\right)^T=I^T \quad \Rightarrow \quad \left(A^{-1}\right)^TA^T=I 
$$

so $A^T$ has an inverse that is $\left(A^{-1}\right)^T$. Now you can prove that $\left(A^{-1}\right)^T=\left(A^T\right)^{-1}$ .

Answer (score 1):

@Emilio gives a direct proof. One can also use determinants. Note that a matrix $X$ is invertible if and only if $\det X\neq 0$. Since $\det A=\det A^\top$, it follows that $A$ is invertible if and only if $A^\top$ is invertible.